# Display source html in iframe on rollover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a db with one field containing the source html of webpages. I have a table that shows the url that leads to the source HTML.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This is a Td</td>
        <td>This is a Td</td>
        <td class="hover">URL1</td>
        <td>This is a Td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="hover">URL1</td>
        <td>This is a Td</td>
        <td>This is a Td</td>        
        <td>This is a Td</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="stuff">
</div>
```

when I roll over a url in the table , I want to display the associated db HTML in an iframe.

based on:

```
http://jsbin.com/urarem/3/edit?html,css,output
```

which appears to do exactly what I want, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover').on('mouseover', function() {
        var html = '<a href="URL"></a><div class="box"><iframe src="URL" width = "500px" height = "500px"></iframe></div>';
        $('.stuff').html(html);
    });
```

Assuming I dynamically load the html source into the variable 'html' on rollover , how do I display this in an Iframe as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just get the `value` or `innerHTML` (depending on how the original HTML is laid out), and then load that into the `src` of the `iframe`.  You can do it like this:

JS:

```
$('.hover').on('mouseover', function(e) {
    var url = $(this).html();
    $('.stuff').attr('src',url).show();
}).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
   $('.stuff').hide().removeAttr('src'); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This is a Td</td>
        <td>This is a Td</td>
        <td class="hover">www.wikipedia.com</td>
        <td>This is a Td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="hover">www.google.com</td>
        <td>This is a Td</td>
        <td>This is a Td</td>        
        <td>This is a Td</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<iframe class="stuff">
</iframe>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgc33s38/) example.

Comment: Thank you that's great! I'm actually trying to dynamically add the html to the td in the table I'm rolling over, but you've got me much closer to that with your example.