# Dynamically changing table td to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

this is a follow up question to [Display source html in iframe on rollover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441391/display-source-html-in-iframe-on-rollover). I have a db with one field containing the source html of webpages. I have a table that shows the url that leads to the source HTML.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This is a Td</td>
        <td>This is a Td</td>
        <td>URL1</td>
        <td>This is a Td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >URL1</td>
        <td>This is a Td</td>
        <td>This is a Td</td>        
        <td>This is a Td</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

when I roll over a url in the table , I want to display the associated db HTML in a dynamically created iframe, inserted at the td . then when I roll off the td I'd like the original contents to be inserted back into the td.

based on:

```
http://jsbin.com/urarem/3/edit?html,css,output
```

which appears to do exactly what I want, I have:

```
   var html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>";
 var iframe = '<a href="URL"></a><div class="box"><iframe src="URL" width = "500px" height = "500px"></iframe></div>';

var contents = "";
$('td').on('mouseover', function(e) {
    contents = $(this).html();
    console.log(contents);
    if (contents.match("^http")) {
        $(this).html(iframe);
     $(this).attr('src',html).show();
    }}).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
   $(this).hide().removeAttr('src');
     $(this).innerHTML = contents;
});
```

Please see

```
http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/ep0hjy1f/5/
```

Unfortunately, no iframe is being created . How do I get this working?

addendum:

just to explain further I have a table that contains urls and corresponding html:

```
id   url                          html
1   https://www.yahoo.com/        <!DOCTYPE html><html><body>.....
2   https://stackoverflow.com/     <!DOCTYPE html><html><body>.....
```

when I roll over a table containing https://stackoverflow.com/, I want to display its corresponding html from the db in an iframe. In the fiddle I'm trying to simulate this html with:

```
var html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1) You are looking for `^http` but the URLs on your page don't contain that prefix.

2) You are calling `attr()` on the `td` rather than the `iframe` inside it.

3) Assorted typos.

4) Calling `hide()` during mouseleave is unnecessary and makes parts of your table disappear.

```
var html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>";
 var iframe = '<a href="URL"></a><div class="box"><iframe src="URL" width = "500px" height = "500px"></iframe></div>';

var contents = "";
$('td').on('mouseover', function(e) {
    contents = $(this).html();
    console.log(contents);
    if (contents.match("^http")) {
        $(this).html(iframe);
     $(this).find('iframe').attr('src',contents).show();
    }}).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  // $(this).hide().removeAttr('src');
     $(this).innerHTML = contents;
});
```

Also note that many websites, such as google.com, use the X-Frame-Options HTTP header to prevent themselves from being shown in an iframe (for security reasons).  This is why Google does not work on your page, but Wikipedia does.

Comment: Tthank you, I've made some changes and the updated fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/ep0hjy1f/13/, but it is still not working correctly with the html sample not being shown and the iframe not closing on mouseleave.

Comment: The src attribute on an iframe needs a URL, not raw HTML.  Assign a URL that points to your server app that generates the HTML to be displayed (which I take it you are pulling from your database).

Comment: My original question , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441391/display-source-html-in-iframe-on-rollover was about how to add preexisting HTML (in my case from a db table) to an iframe. I thought Eclecticist meant that you could add HTML to it directly. If this is impossible , could you give me an example on how to " Assign a URL that points to your server app that generates the HTML"

Comment: The iframe is not closing due to a combination of two things: 1) Use either $(this).html(contents) or this.innerHTML = contents to restore the original contents of the td.  $(this).innerHTML = contents is a mix of jQuery and non-jQuery, and just assigns to a previously undefined 'innerHTML' property of your anonymous jQuery collection.  2) Use 'mouseenter' rather than 'mouseover'.  'mouseover' bubbles, so your code is receiving it twice, and the second time, the contents variable gets corrupted.

Comment: Re: URLs and iframes, I'm not completely clear on what you want to do.  Do you want to 1) show the webpage in the iframe, 2) show the HTML source for the webpage in the frame (as if you had used "View Source" from the browser menu), or 3) show a cached version of the webpage that you stored in your database?

Comment: Please see addendum above:

Comment: Ok, so say that you have a file on your server called retrieveHtml.php.  You would set the iframe's src attribute to something like retrieveHtml.php?url=www.google.com.  The server would then get the URL from the variable $_GET['url'], look it up in the db, and return the stored HTML for it.  (This example assumes PHP, adjust as needed for whichever server-side language you are using.)

Comment: OK thank you, I'll look into this further. it seems awfully complicated and a real workaround when I have the HTML ready to go. I appreciate your taking the time to explain this. - Bill